# Не могу найти решение к циклу while с использованием selenium,как решить?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Как мне сделать так ,чтобы в моем коде при определённых условиях открывался цикл ,который потом анализирует изменения данных из переменных selenium,а в случае их изменений закрывает цикл,и запускает новый? Вот, что я пробовал...

```py
elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@title]")
for elem in elems[0:1]:
    cc = (elem.get_attribute("title"))
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.j_2Hd').send_keys(cc)
#refresh 
ele = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@title]")
el = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@title]")
for ele in el[0:1]:
    rr = (ele.get_attribute("title"))
while cc == rr 
    browser.get('website.com')
```

*P.S Извините за такой кривой код ,я в этом неопытен*

Comment: После `while` двоеточие пропустили.

Comment: Немного непонятно, как то, что Вы написали перед кодом, соотносится с самим кодом, но, чтобы "закрыть" цикл, используйте `break`. Чтобы получить более исчерпывающий ответ, напишите в виде комментариев к коду, где Вы в коде реализуете то, что у Вас написано в описании.

Comment: В чем смысл вот этого цикла: `for ele in el[0:1]` он всегда будет выполняться только по первому элементу коллекции. Сделайте без цикла, просто вот так: `rr = (el[0].get_attribute("title"))`

Comment: смысл в том ,чтобы выводилась не вся инфа из сайта,а только одно значение...